# How to solve MIME type error for a svelte file?

Tags: svelte

I am just getting into incorporating svelte into my firebase project, however I ran into a problem:

> eventDispatcher.svelte:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "false". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

This is the code in eventDispatcher.svelte:

```
<script context="module">
   // import from svelte
   import { createEventDispatcher } from "./svelte/internal";

   // store the function in a constant
   const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

   // export 'dispatch'
   export { dispatch };
</script>
```

as you can see, I tried setting the MIME type to module, however it just doesn't.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These code comments need to burn in a fire.

Comment: `createEventDispatcher` can be imported directly from `'svelte'`. Also, it makes no sense to try and export a dispatcher from `context="module"`, each component instance should create its own.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought I needed a .svelte file to use svelte. I only picked it up a week ago and am not very familiar with best practices. Sorry if the code burned your eyes. Also what does "each component instance should create it's own" mean ? Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: It means that `createEventDispatcher` is called in a Svelte script block without `context="module"` in every component that needs a dispatcher and that the resulting function is not shared between components (e.g. via import/export as you tried).

Comment: (If the result of `createEventDispatcher` were meant to be shared, Svelte would simply directly export a `dispatch` function.)